# CSS - How to shift a span elements content downward

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a drop down menu button that sits in a span:

[image]

Don't mind that it's not horizontally centered (that's just a poor screen shot). What I want to do is vertically center it, but not by using `position`. Instead I would like to *shift* it down by a pixel or two. How can I do this?

Here's my styling:

```
<span
  className={ 'arrow-down' }
  style={{
    float: 'right',
    display: 'block',
    height: '12px',
    lineHeight: '12px',
    width: '12px',
    borderRadius: '30px',
    backgroundColor: '#ffbf44',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'top',
    fontSize: '1.25em',
  }}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `margin-top`:

```
<span
  className={ 'arrow-down' }
  style={{
    float: 'right',
    display: 'block',
    height: '12px',
    lineHeight: '12px',
    width: '12px',
    borderRadius: '30px',
    backgroundColor: '#ffbf44',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'top',
    fontSize: '1.25em',
    marginTop: '2px'
  }}/>
```

This is effectively what @AllanJiang proposed with paddingTop, but margin won't affect the clickable size of the element, if that's an issue.

Comment: Do you know how I would add an outline around it? Sorry, forgot to ask that in the post. `outline` doesn't work

Comment: You would us CSS property `border`. A possible value could be `solid 1px #000000` for a solid black border.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use flex box positioning:

```
spanStyle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 2, <--- in case you want to adjust the position manually
}
```